# Find convex hull or simplex on hypersphere that enclose all vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, spherical-geometry, convex-hulls

Assume that we have x1,x2,...xn vectors in d-dimensional (d>=64) hypersphere, How can we find a convex hull or simplex for all of them that encloses all the vectors? can we describe that shape with limited number of vectors?

Comment: What sort of description are you looking for? "Convex hull of this set of vectors" is itself a complete description.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a mathematical description that is dependent on the vectors on the sphere, something like distribution of vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any finite set of vectors $V = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$, the convex hull is given by $$\mathcal H(V)=\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_kv_k\;\middle|\; \forall k, a_k > 0; \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = 1\right\}$$

Note that this is the entire hull, not just the boundary hypersurface. Also, a point in the hull may be given by many different coefficient sequences $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$.

---

Added: to show that the set defined above is indeed the convex hull of a finite set.

Convex hulls $C(V)$ and the sets
$$\mathcal H(V) := \left\{\sum_{k=0}^n a_kv_k\;\middle|\; n \in \Bbb N; \forall k, a_k > 0\text{ and }v_k \in V; \sum_{k=0}^n a_k = 1\right\}$$
satisfy a similar property:

- For any set of vectors $V$ and any vector $x, C(V \cup \{x\})$ is the union of all line segments connecting $x$ to elements of $C(V)$.
- For any set of vectors $V$ and any vector $x, \mathcal H(V\cup \{x\})$ is the union of all line segments connecting $x$ to elements of $\mathcal H(V)$.

To prove the first, Let $\displaystyle C' = \bigcup_{w \in C(V)} \overline{xw}$. Note that $C(V \cup \{x\})$ is a convex set containing $V$, so as the intersection of all such sets, $C(V) \subseteq C(V \cup \{x\})$. And since $C(V \cup \{x\})$ is convex, it must therefore contain all line segments between $x$ and points of $C(V)$. That is, $C' \subseteq C(V\cup \{x\})$.

Conversely, given any two points $a,b \in C'$, there must be $p,q \in C(V)$ such that $a$ lies on $\overline{xp}$ and $b$ lies on $\overline{xq}$. Now $\triangle xpq$ has its base $\overline{pq}$ in $C(V)$, and every point in its interior lines on a segment from $x$ to a point on $\overline{pq}$, and is therefore in $C'$. In particular, the line segmqent $\overline{ab}$ is interior to the triangle, and so is in $C'$. Since $a, b$ where arbitrary, $C'$ is convex. And so $C(V\cup \{x\}) \subseteq C'$.

Hence $\displaystyle C(V\cup \{x\}) = C' = \bigcup_{w \in C(V)} \overline{xw}$ as required.

To prove the second, let $\displaystyle H = \bigcup_{w \in \mathcal H(V)} \overline{xw}$. Note that the elements of $\mathcal H(V\cup\{x\})$ that do not include $x$ as one of the $v_k$ in the sum are exactly the elements of $\mathcal H(V)$, so $\mathcal H(V)\subseteq \mathcal H(V\cup\{x\})$. Further, if $v = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kv_k \in \mathcal H(V\cup\{x\})$ with $v_0 = x$, $v_k \in \mathcal H(V)$ for all $k > 0$, and $a_0 \ne 1$, we can rewrite the sum as
$$v = a_0x + (1 - a_0)\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{a_k}{1-a_0}v_k$$
and note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{a_k}{1-a_0} = \dfrac 1{1-a_0}\sum_{k=1}^n a_n = \dfrac 1{1-a_0}(1-a_0) = 1$$
since $\sum_{k=0}^n a_n = 1$. So $w = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{1-a_0}v_k \in \mathcal H(V)$ and $v = a_0x + (1-a_0)w$ is a point on the line segment connecting $x$ and $w$. Thus $\mathcal H(V\cup\{x\}) \subseteq H$.

Conversely, if $v\in H$, then there exists a $t \in [0,1]$ and a $w \in \mathcal H(V)$ such that $v = tx + (1-t)w$. Now by definition, $w = \sum_{k=1}^n a_kv_k$ with all $v_k \in V$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = 1$. Let $v_0 = x, b_0 = t$ and for all $k > 0, b_k = (1-t)a_k$. Then

$$\begin{align}v &= tx + (1-t)w\\&= tx + \sum_{k=1}^n (1-t)a_kv_k\\&=b_0v_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n b_kv_k=\sum_{k=0}^n b_kv_k\end{align}$$
And $$\sum_{k=0}^n b_k = b_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n b_k = t + (1-t)\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = t + (1-t)1 = 1$$
Hence $v \in \mathcal H(V\cup\{x\})$. Since $\mathcal H(V\cup\{x\}) \subseteq H$ and $H \subseteq \mathcal H(V\cup\{x\})$, the two are equal, as required.

Now given any finite set $V = \{v_0, \ldots, v_N\}$, we can set $V_n = \{v_0, \ldots v_n\}$ for all $n \le N$. Since $V_0$ consists of a single point, it is trivially convex, so $C(V_0) = V_0$. But also by the definition, $\mathcal H(V_0) = V_0$. In particular, $C(V_0) = \mathcal H(V_0)$.

But then $C(V_1)$ and $\mathcal H(V_1)$ are both the union of all line segments connecting $v_1$ to elements of $V_0$, and thus are equal as well. Continuing inductively $C(V_n) = \mathcal H(V_n)$ for every $n$.

Comment: Thanks Paul, your answer has some problems: 1-It is no guarantee to be convex, for example you can set all of ak with 1/n so how can guarantee that it is a convex hull. 2-We need a convex hull of them so some of vectors may belongs to others convex hull and we don't want to set coefficient to them in our final convex hull expression.

Comment: You are mistaken. That is exactly the convex hull of a finite set of vectors, as can be shown inductively on the set size. In fact, it is the convex hull for infinite sets as well, if changed to be the sums over all possible finite subsets.

Comment: I've added a demonstration of the finite version to the post.

Comment: Thanks Paul, you're right. You view the problem as a perspective of all convex combination of vectors.

Comment: You asked for the convex hull. This is what the convex hull is. This particular representation may not be what you are after, but you haven't described what you are after well enough to allow anyone to give you something else.

Comment: I would like to find a closed form formula for the boundary of this convex hull and i would like to find one or at most K (K<<n) proxy with good approximation instead of all original vectors. both of them is what i want to find. your answer is right to my question, and as you said, my question was not exact what i was wanted, but it helped me.
do you have any idea about boundary and proxy?